# Proper way of loading Image/Texture Sprites on GameScreen in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, asset-management

Good day everybody I'm new to this framework **LibGdx**. I need advice/suggestion for my game.Is it okay if I load my images in a single class? I'm a beginner and  start learning LibGdx. I already coded my game screen and it works perfectly as I expected. My concern is how about the performance of this in other device? I don't know how to implement `Assetmanager`.

Here is my code it works fine but I think it is not the proper way of loading images. Any suggestion help are much appreciated :)

```
public class IngamedayOne implements Screen ,InputProcessor {
final MyGdxGame game;
// Constant rows and columns of the sprite sheet
private static final int FRAME_COLS = 5, FRAME_ROWS = 1;
private boolean peripheralAvailable;
private static final float ACCELERATION     = 20f;
// Objects used
Animation<TextureRegion> walkAnimation; // Must declare frame type (TextureRegion)
Texture  left_paw,right_paw,progressbar_background,progressbar_knob,pause,meter,open_box;
Texture carpet,desk,plants,square_carpet,pauseImg,pause_cancel,retry,dayselect_img,household_select,back_to_main_menu;

SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Sprite catsprite,sprite_shoes,sprite_plant,sprite_ball,dogsprite;
private  Texture Background1,Background2,Background3;
float yMax, yCoordBg1, yCoordBg2,yCoordDesk;
final int BACKGROUND_MOVE_SPEED = -200;

ImageButton left_paw_btn,right_paw_btn,pause_btnDialog,pause_btn_exit,retry_btn,dayselect_btn,select_household,back_to_main_menu_btn;
Image pauseImg_text;
Viewport viewport;
private Stage stage;
// A variable for tracking elapsed time for the animation
float stateTime;
private TextureRegion myTextureRegion;
TextureRegion textureRegion;
private TextureRegionDrawable myTexRegionDrawable;
private boolean isPause;
private Group pauseGroup;
Texture cat,dog;



private float yPosition = -40;
//Screen Size
OrthographicCamera camera;
float catSpeed = 50.0f; // 10 pixels per second.
float catX;
float catY;
float x=0,y=0;


public IngamedayOne(final MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(false);
    Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
    Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport( 720, 1280));
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280 ,720);
    camera.update();

    camera.setToOrtho(false, 720, 1280);
    camera.translate( 1280/2, 720/2 );
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    // Load the sprite sheet as a texture
    cat = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat.png"));
    catsprite = new Sprite(cat);
    catX=300;
    catY=0;

    dog = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("equip/Dog.png"));
    dogsprite = new Sprite(dog);
    dogsprite.setPosition(20,580);


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( this);
    peripheralAvailable = Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer);
    int orientation = Gdx.input.getRotation();
    Input.Orientation nativeOrientation = Gdx.input.getNativeOrientation();

    viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    //Display Items
    carpet = new Texture("equip/carpet2.png");
    desk = new Texture("equip/Desk.png");
    open_box = new Texture("equip/open box.png");

    square_carpet = new Texture("equip/Carpet.png");

    plants = new Texture("equip/Plants.png");
    sprite_plant = new Sprite(plants);

    sprite_shoes = new Sprite(new Texture("equip/Shoes.png"));
    sprite_shoes.setPosition(260,580);

    sprite_ball = new Sprite(new Texture("equip/Basketball.png"));
    sprite_ball.setPosition(260,300);
    // Progressbar
    progressbar_background = new Texture("progression_map.png");
    progressbar_knob = new Texture("cat_head.png");
    //pause
    pause = new Texture("pause.png");
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(pause);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    pause_btnDialog = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    pause_btnDialog.setPosition(580,1150);

    stage.addActor(pause_btnDialog); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    pause_btnDialog.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            System.out.println("Pause Button Pressed");
            //Show Pause Screen menu
            pause();
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(pause_btnDialog);
    meter = new Texture("meter.png");
    //background
    Background1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("floor.png"));
    Background2 = Background1;
    yMax = -1270;
    yCoordBg1 = yMax*(-1);
    yCoordBg2 = 0;
    yCoordDesk = 0;


    // Use the split utility method to create a 2D array of TextureRegions. This is
    // possible because this sprite sheet contains frames of equal size and they are
    // all aligned.

    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(cat, cat.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS, cat.getHeight()/ FRAME_ROWS);
    // Place the regions into a 1D array in the correct order, starting from the top
    // left, going across first. The Animation constructor requires a 1D array.
    TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Initialize the Animation with the frame interval and array of frames
    walkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.200f, walkFrames);
    // Instantiate a SpriteBatch for drawing and reset the elapsed animation
    // time to 0
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stateTime = 0f;

    //left_control
    left_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("left_paw.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(left_paw);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    left_paw_btn = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    left_paw_btn.setPosition(10,25);

    stage.addActor(left_paw_btn); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    left_paw_btn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Left Button Pressed");
            //Start Animation
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(left_paw_btn);
    //right_control
    right_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(right_paw);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    right_paw_btn = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    right_paw_btn.setPosition(517,25);

    stage.addActor(right_paw_btn); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    right_paw_btn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Right Button Pressed");
            //Start Animation
            stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time
            camera.update();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(right_paw_btn);
}
public enum State
{
    PAUSE,
    RUN,
    RESUME,
    STOPPED
}
private State state = State.RUN;
@Override
public void show() {
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // clear previous frame
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time
    yCoordBg1+= BACKGROUND_MOVE_SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    yCoordBg2 = yCoordBg1 + yMax;  // We move the background, not the camera
    yCoordDesk = BACKGROUND_MOVE_SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (yCoordBg1 <= 2) {
        yCoordBg1 = yMax*(-1);
        yCoordBg2 = 0;
    }
    spriteBatch.begin();
    if(this.state==State.RESUME);
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    spriteBatch.draw(Background1, 0,yCoordBg1);
    spriteBatch.draw(Background2, 0,yCoordBg2);
    //spriteBatch.draw(square_carpet,150,2,408,800);
    //spriteBatch.draw(carpet,230,980,250,260);
    //sprite_shoes.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.draw(open_box,490,690);
    sprite_ball.draw(spriteBatch);
    dogsprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame,catX,catY); // Draw current frame at (50, 50)
    // spriteBatch.draw(desk,10,1150,160,260);
     //spriteBatch.draw(plants,500,700,200,260);
    spriteBatch.draw(meter,190,990);
    spriteBatch.draw(progressbar_background,20,1170);
    spriteBatch.draw(progressbar_knob,18,1170);


        //Moving player on desktop
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
            catX -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
            catX += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
            catY += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))
            catY -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * catSpeed;
        //Mobile acceleration
        if (Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer)) {
            catX -= Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
            catY += Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
        }
    if (catY > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 100) {
        catY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 100;
    }
        if (catX < 0) {
            catX = 0;
        }
        if (catX > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 250) {
            catX = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 250;
        }
    if(this.state==State.RESUME) {
        switch (state) {
            case RUN:
                //do suff here
                break;
            case PAUSE:
                break;
            case RESUME:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    spriteBatch.end();
    stage.act(); //acting a stage to calculate positions of actors etc
    stage.draw(); //drawing it to render all
}
// Check if Polygon intersects Rectangle
// Check if Polygon intersects Circle
private boolean isCollision(Polygon polygon, Circle c) {
    float[] vertices = polygon.getTransformedVertices();
    Vector2 center = new Vector2(c.x, c.y);
    float squareRadius = c.radius * c.radius;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 2) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle(new Vector2(
                    vertices[vertices.length - 2],
                    vertices[vertices.length - 1]), new Vector2(
                    vertices[i], vertices[i + 1]), center, squareRadius))
                return true;
        } else {
            if (Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle(new Vector2(
                    vertices[i - 2], vertices[i - 1]), new Vector2(
                    vertices[i], vertices[i + 1]), center, squareRadius))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
}
@Override
public void pause() {
    this.state = State.PAUSE;
    pauseGroup = new Group();
    Image semiTransparentBG=new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("backgroundimage.png")));
    // setSize(Size of screen) and make it semi transparent.
    pauseGroup.addActor(semiTransparentBG);
    //create all other pause UI buttons with listener and add to pauseGroup
    //cancel
    pause_cancel = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pausemenu/exit.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(pause_cancel);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    pause_btn_exit = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    pause_btn_exit.setPosition(550,1130);

    stage.addActor(pause_btn_exit); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    pause_btn_exit.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Cancel Button Pressed");
            resume();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(pause_btn_exit);
    pauseGroup.addActor(pause_btn_exit);

    pauseImg = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pausemenu/pause_text.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(pauseImg);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    pauseImg_text = new Image(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    pauseImg_text.setPosition(260,970);
    pauseGroup.addActor(pauseImg_text);

    //retry
    retry = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pausemenu/retry.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(retry);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    retry_btn = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    retry_btn.setPosition(200,700);

    stage.addActor(retry_btn); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    retry_btn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Button Pressed");
            //resume
            game.setScreen(new IngamedayOne(game));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(retry_btn);
    pauseGroup.addActor(retry_btn);
    //Day Select
    dayselect_img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pausemenu/day_select.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(dayselect_img);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    dayselect_btn = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    dayselect_btn.setPosition(180,490);
    stage.addActor(dayselect_btn); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    dayselect_btn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println(" Button Pressed");
            game.setScreen(new SelectDiffculty(game));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(dayselect_btn);
    pauseGroup.addActor(dayselect_btn);
    //House Select
    household_select = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pausemenu/household_select.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(household_select);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    select_household = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    select_household.setPosition(180,300);

    stage.addActor(select_household); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    select_household.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println(" Button Pressed");
            //resume
            game.setScreen(new SelectHouseHold(game));

        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(select_household);
    pauseGroup.addActor(select_household);
    //Back to main menu
    back_to_main_menu = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pausemenu/back_to_main_menu.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(back_to_main_menu);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    back_to_main_menu_btn = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    back_to_main_menu_btn.setPosition(40,80);
    stage.addActor(back_to_main_menu_btn); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    back_to_main_menu_btn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println(" Button Pressed");
            //resume
            game.setScreen(new MainScreen(game));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(back_to_main_menu_btn);
    pauseGroup.addActor(back_to_main_menu_btn);
    stage.addActor(pauseGroup);
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    this.state = State.RESUME;
    pauseGroup.remove();
}
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void hide() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() { // SpriteBatches and Textures must always be disposed

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use Assetmanager because that way when the application exits and you call manager.dispose() it automatically releases all resources you loaded.

Example from the wiki [Assetmanager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets)

```
AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();
```

This sets up a standard AssetManager, with all the loaders libgdx has in store at the moment. Let's see how the loading mechanism works.

Loading a specific asset is simple:

```
 manager.load("resource path/mytexture.png", Texture.class); 
manager.load("resource path/myfont.fnt", BitmapFont.class); 
manager.load("resource path/mymusic.ogg", Music.class);
```

So far we only queued assets to be loaded. The AssetManager does not yet load anything. To kick this off we have to call AssetManager#update() continuously, say in our ApplicationListener#render() method:

```
    public MyAppListener implements ApplicationListener 
        { 
        public void render() 
        { if(manager.update()) { 
        // we are done loading, let's move to another screen! 
        } 

    // display loading information 
float progress = manager.getProgress() ... left to the reader ... 
    } 
    }
```

If you want to block and make sure all assets are loaded you can call:

```
manager.finishLoading();
```

Getting assets is also easy as 1 2 3

```
manager.get("resource path",classtype);
```

Example

```
Texture texture = manager.get("resource path/mytexture.png",Texture.class);
```

Disposing of the manager is also easy yust call

```
manager.dispose(); // gets rid of all the assets
```

Hope this helps and take a look at the wiki 
PS made this on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your stuff in same class but it's not a good practice, I advice you to use LoadingScreen to load your assets.

[This](https://github.com/Matsemann/libgdx-loading-screen) page explains how to create simple LoadingScreen.

[This](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) page very well explains how to use `AsssetManager`